# How to Blur Touched Area in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, photo, blur

I'm trying to blur touched area in android. the code below blurs the whole image. But I want to blur touched area on the screen.

```
public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

How can I blur area that touched by user on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

It's blurring the whole image because ScriptIntrinsicBlur render script running for every pixels. Now in order to blur only specific pixels you need to first find out the pixels you want to blur. Then to blur them you have two possible ways.

1. You can either use the ScriptIntrinsicBlur render script. In that case while populating the pixels in the allocation object you have to populate your "tmpIn" allocation object only with the pixels you need to blur. Then after blurring finished you have to replace the original image's specific pixels with pixels of "tmpOut" allocation object.
2. Or you can write your custom render script to blur specific pixels only.

Hope it helps. Let me know, if I can help you further. Happy coding :)

Comment: We used xfermode and renderscript together and solved touched area blur. Thank you

Comment: xfermode is on cpu I think. @Md can you give some reference for custom renderscript so everything is done efficiently at once on gpu?